# Django is not loading template form

Tags: django, forms, url, view

I don't know why is not loading the template but every time I click in an url the page auto-reload and not load the template, here is my code:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^pedidos/add',forms.PedidoCreateView.as_view(), name="pedido_add")
```

**forms.py**

```
class PedidoCreateView(CreateView):
   template_name = 'ventas/form_pedido.html'
   model = Pedido
   form_class = PedidoModelForm
   success_url = 'ventas/pedidos.html'


   def form_valid(self, form):
       form.save(commit=True)
       return super(PedidoCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**form_pedido.html**

```
{% extends '_layouts/base.html' %}
{% load url from future %}


{% block breadcrumb%}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'ventas:pedidos_list' %}">Pedidos</a>
        <span class="divider">
            <i class="icon-angle-right"></i>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li class="active">Nuevo Pedido</li>
{% endblock %}

{% block page_content %}
    <form class ="form" id="form" method="POST" action="{{ request.path }}">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3>Editar Empleado</h3>
    </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            {% csrf_token %}
             {{ form.non_field_errors }}
               {{ form_errors }}
            {{form.as_p}}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="cerrar btn">Cerrar</a>
            <input type="submit" class="guardar btn btn-primary" value="Guardar">
     </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}


{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

**link**

```
<a href="{% url 'ventas:pedido_add' %}" class="btn btn-app btn-success">
```

For sure has to be some error that I'm not able to see now, I prove with other similar views and I don't have any problems, what could it be?

Comment: not enough information, is there any errors?, try stripping extra data and start from the basic CreateView view with model and template only and then add stuff successfully.